# How to add Google Calendar in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in iOS. and I created Google Calendar with the help of this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios.

[image]

It fetch the event which is created in Google Calendar.But I need to show Google Calendar in my App. Thanks in Advance .
For Event I used a code

```
EKEventStore *store = [EKEventStore new];
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) { return; }
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        event.title = @"Birthday XYZ";
        event.startDate = [NSDate date]; //today
        event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
        event.calendar = [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
        NSError *err = nil;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
        // self.savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;  //save the event id if you want to access this later
    }];
```

But this code is not create event.

Comment: If you are asking for a framework to show (UI stuff) a calendar, there is no framework from Apple. There are some on CocoaPods/GitHub/CocoaControls.

Comment: @Larme can you please suggest me any link with proper UI for calendar.